# Using stdout/stderr/stdin streams behind haskell's FFI

Tags: c++, haskell, io, ghc, ffi

I'm developing a small haskell program that uses an external static library I've developed in C++. It accesses the lib through ghc's FFI (foreign function interface). Inside this library I would like to do some output to the console. However, it *looks* to me like the c++ side of things does not have a correct handle to stdout because output does not appear on the console. So then, my questions are:

- Does ghc hijack these three streams (stdout, stdin, stderr) or is libstdc++ simply not initializing them because I'm linking with ghc?
- Do my FFI imports need to be "safe" if they write to stdout?
- How can I pass stdout to a C function? Should I simply pass it directly or do I need a C type?

**Additional notes:** I'm linking libstdc++ directly to the executable (i.e. ghc -lstdc++ ...) which I naively assumed would be the correct way of doing this. Seems to work well

**Disclaimer:** Still pretty new to Haskell, so baby steps for now ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem does appear to be that libstdc++ is not being initialized.  I'm not entirely sure why — `-lstdc++` is sufficient on my system — but see if it works the other way around.

`Main.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where
foreign export ccall "Main_main" main :: IO ()
foreign import ccall driver_callback :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Now in Haskell" >> driver_callback
```

`driver.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
# include "HsFFI.h"

#  ifdef __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
#   include "Main_stub.h"
    extern void __stginit_Main(void);
#  endif

    void driver_callback(void) {
        std::cout << "Back in C++" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);
# ifdef __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
    hs_add_root(__stginit_Main);
# endif

    std::cout << "Starting in C++" << std::endl;

    Main_main();

    hs_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
$ ghc -c --make Main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
$ ghc --make -no-hs-main -lstdc++ Main driver.cc
Linking Main ...
$ ./Main
Starting in C++
Now in Haskell
Back in C++
```

Comment: It turned out the problem was between the chair and the keyboard. I made a silly unrelated mistake due to my inexperience with Haskell. Your answer was quite helpful as it helped me establish that the stdlibc++ does actually initialize correctly and I was merely being a bit of a moron. For this reason you get my accepted answer. Thanks!